# Restriction to the maximal torus

Tags: algebraic-groups, tannakian-category, grothendieck-rings

$\DeclareMathOperator\ad{ad}\DeclareMathOperator\ind{ind}\DeclareMathOperator\res{res}\DeclareMathOperator\Rep{Rep}\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}$Let me say that I am kind of sure that all the things I am going to ask are manifestly false for an expert, because I don't have much confidence with this stuff. Thus, take this question as finding counterexamples to non straightforward things :)

Suppose $G$ is a semisimple split affine algebraic group over $k$. 
For an algebraic group we denote by $\ad(G)$ the associated Lie algebra.
We know that $G$ is determined by the associated root datum, which is constructed in the following way:

1. Let $T$ be a maximal torus (which is split by hp). Every representation of $T$ splits in one dimensional reps determined by a "weight" $\alpha \in \ad(T)^* $.
2. Thus, $\res_T(\ad G)$ gives us a (finite) list of weights in $\ad(T)^*$ which determines the root datum.

Note that the weights that appears can be computed by $K_0(\res_T([\ad G]) )$ at the level of Grothendieck groups.

> (1) Can one understand who is $[\ad G]$ in $K_0(\Rep G)$? In other words, if two groups have same $K_0$, are the element $[\ad G]$, $[\ad G']$ equal?

In the finite group case over complex numbers, one can easily see that $H \to G$ is injective iff for every representation $V \neq 0$ of $H$, $\ind_H^G V \neq 0$.

Moreover, this can be checked on Grothendieck groups. Take the scalar product on $K_0(\Rep G)$ given by $\langle [V], [W] \rangle = \dim_{\mathbb C} \Hom(V,W)$. Then $ \langle [\ind] V, W \rangle = \langle V, [\res] W \rangle$, which determines $[\ind]$ as the adjoint in linear algebra of $\res$ because the scalar product is positive definite.

> (2) Does this criterion holds in general context? Can one check this criterion only on Grothendieck groups?

If this is true, let me call a map of neutral Tannakian categories $C \to D$, pseudo injective if the adjoint $D \to C$ sends non zero objects to non zero objects (somehow the "kernel" of the adjoint is zero), and analogously for maps between their Grothendieck rings.

Now saying that $T$ is a maximal torus is like saying that $\Rep G \to \Rep T$ is maximal pseudoinjective from $\Rep G$ to a category of the form $\Rep(k^*)^{\otimes n}$. Note that $K_0(\Rep(k^*)) \simeq \mathbb Z[x,x^{-1}]$ in characteristic zero and $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^{p-1}-1) $ in characteristic $p$ (maybe? Not sure about char $p$).

> Is it true that $K_0(\Rep G) \to K_0(\Rep T)$ is a maximal pseudoinjective map from $K_0(\Rep G)$ to a ring of the form $\mathbb Z[x_1^{\pm 1}, \ldots, x_n^{\pm 1} ]$ (and analogously for characteristic $p$)?

If 1 is false, one has a possibility that all that kind of maps come from maximal tori. The question in this case is:

> Do you think there is a possibility that in the general case $K_0(\Rep G)$ and $[\ad G] \in K_0(\Rep G)$ determine the group?

Indeed, there is no reference to a maximal torus now.

Of course, one must also remember the $K_0$ of the fiber functor $\Rep G \to \operatorname{Vec}_k$, which gives a map $K_0(\Rep G) \to \mathbb{Z}$ remembering the dimension of things.

If 1 is true, there should be some maximal pseudoinjective maps from $K_0(\Rep G)$ to a ring of that form which do not come from maximal tori, otherwise one could reconstruct the $G$ from $K_0(\Rep G)$, and this is not true even for finite groups (knowing $K_0$ in this case is like knowing the character table).

In this case the question is:

> Can you find extra data you have to remember from $\Rep G$—that can be abstractly formulated for a general group—to understand if a map $K_0(\Rep G) \to \mathbb{Z}[x_1^{\pm 1}, \ldots, x_n^{\pm 1}]$ comes from a maximal torus?

EDIT: all the Grothendieck rings $A$ that appear have a presentation of the form $\mathbb Z[x_i]/(x_ix_j - \sum n_{ij}^k x_k)$ where $n$ are naturals, and come equipped with a dimension morphism $A \to Z$. When I talk about morphisms between these kind of rings, I mean ring morphisms $f$ that commute with the dimension morphism and such that in this presentation $f(x_i) = \sum a_i^j y_j$ with $a_i^j$ natural numbers. Otherwise, of course there is no possibility that such morphisms lift to the corresponding rep categories!

Comment: What is an example of $G$ and $G'$ with the same $K_0(\operatorname{Rep} \cdot)$?  (Also, unless there's some sort of rigidity (i.e., only trivial automorphisms), it doesn't seem to make sense to ask whether elements in two isomorphic structures are the same; maybe the question is whether there is *some* isomorphism that carries one to the other?)

Comment: Also, the description of the root datum is a bit truncated:  one wants not just the set $\Phi$ of weights of $T$ on $\mathfrak g$, but the lattice $X^*(T)$ of characters of $T$ in which $\Phi$ sits.  (Otherwise, one couldn't distinguish $\operatorname{SL}_2$ from $\operatorname{PGL}_2$, or, more generally, distinguish between any pair of isogenous groups.)

Comment: If you take the dihedral group D_4 and the quaternions, they both have grothendieck group $Z[x,y]/( xy-y, y^2-y-x-1)$. For the second question I am sure about the finite dimensional case but not for the infinite. If you take a an automorphism of the grothendieck ring of the form I said, it is in particular a linear automorphism with natural coefficients, so it is a permutation of the variables that preserve the dimension; so being equal means up to permuting variables of the same dimension (or maybe more as I didn't mention multplicativity)

Comment: Sorry, I [meant](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348303/restriction-to-the-maximal-torus#comment872336_348303) an example of a coincidence of $K_0$s for groups as in your condition (split semisimple).  I very much doubt that $[\mathfrak g]$ is preserved by as general an automorphism as you [describe](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348303/restriction-to-the-maximal-torus#comment872340_348303), but I don't think much about algebraic representations, so I could be wrong.

Comment: Well, if the world is fair, a finite simple group should be semisimple as algebraic group, because it doesn't have (solvable) subgroups at all. As I said, the K_0 for finite groups is equivalent to the character table. I would be surprised to discover that simple finte groups are classified by the character table...

Comment: Ah but maybe they are not split . I don't know what does split means for finite groups, maybe one can look into simple finite subgroups of GL_n(F_p) with an explicit torus of diagonal matrices. Sorry if I am vague but I can't sit down and look up by the moment

Comment: A finite group, regarded as a constant group scheme, is simple because the algebraic condition for simplicity only rules out *infinite* normal subgroups (e.g., $\operatorname{SL}_2$ is simple).  However, (a) it has the trivial Lie algebra, and (b) almost certainly (e.g., for the classification by root data) you wanted to consider groups $G$ that are (algebraically) connected anyway.  I think you are right that split doesn't have an inherent meaning for abstract finite groups.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102193/discussion-between-andrea-marino-and-lspice).